# Detect multiple popups allowed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there some way to detect if a browser will allow multiple popups with a single action (eg Keypress).

An example of this can be found on Kayak.com

If you visit the site in Firefox (Windows) then after you put in your Origin, Destination & Travel dates you are given the option to "Compare Kayak vs Other sites" and there is a "Select All" link. If you click that link, then all checkboxes are ticked & when you click 'Search' then a window for each checkbox opens up.

If you visit the site in Chrome or IE, then after you put in your Origin, Destination & Travel dates there is no "Select All" option allowed. This is because Chrome & IE only allow 1 popup per user action. In this case, the user is forced to click each checkbox individually which opens a new window immediately.

Rather than detect Firefox in the UA string, is there some way to feature detect this? (Without opening test windows).